# css vertical text not working

Tags: css

i am trying to style some text to be vertical. here is my css:

```
h2.verticle{
color:#1a6455;
border:0px solid red;
writing-mode:tb-rl;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
white-space:nowrap;
display:block;
bottom:0;
width:20px;
height:20px;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:normal;
border:none !important;}
```

it works fine in all browsers apart from IE. i used the code from here: http://scottgale.com/blog/css-vertical-text/2010/03/01/

and have tested that site on the same version of IE and it seems to work.

any ideas on what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

try this version:

```
<style>
.verticaltext
    {
        writing-mode: tb-rl;
        filter: flipv fliph;
    }
 </style>

<div class="verticaltext">
    Test-1</div>
<div class="title">
```

and this is the version of that site  http://scottgale.com/blog/css-vertical-text/2010/03/01/

```
vertical-text {
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
border: 0 solid red;
bottom: 0;
color: #333333;
display: block;
font-family: ‘Trebuchet MS’,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: normal;
height: 20px;
text-shadow: 0 0 1px #333333;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: i dont understand how it doesnt work? i have copied the exact css as stated in the tutorial, viewed what i have done on ie and doesnt work, then then the tutorial site does work in ie?